# angularJS - ng-show - error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

that's what I have.

```
  <form action="/asvabo/ChangeCustomerRegister.do" method="post"  
    name="CustomerRegisterForm">
    ...
      <input ... type="text" ... name="order.id" pattern="[0-9]*" required 
        ng-model="orderid" ng-trim="true"/>

      <!-- Label for show that the input is required -->
      <span class="error" 
         ng-show="CustomerRegisterForm.order.id.$error.required">Required!
      </span>
     ....
    </form>
```

I think, there is a problem with the NAME attribute. If i use orderid in both, the input-tag and the following error condition it works.
But we work with Struts and i need the NAME attribute like `xxxx.yyyy`

Is there a way to use this syntax in der `ng-show` exprssion?

Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I looked inside the [form controller source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js):

```
form.$addControl = function(control) {
  // Breaking change - before, inputs whose name was "hasOwnProperty" were quietly ignored
  // and not added to the scope.  Now we throw an error.
  assertNotHasOwnProperty(control.$name, 'input');
  controls.push(control);

  if (control.$name) {
    form[control.$name] = control;
  }
};
```

In your case, the input's `control.$name === "order.id"`, so this what happens:

```
  form["order.id"] = control;
```

#### The solution is to refer the control like so:

```
<span class="error" 
      ng-show="CustomerRegisterForm['order.id'].$error.required">Required!
</span>
```